# Python's `functools.wraps` breaks when keyword only arguments involved

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems like `functools.wraps` breaks the wrapped function when keyword only kinds are involved. Did I find a stlib bug, or is there something I'm missing

Consider this code:

```py
from functools import wraps, WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS, partial

# First, I need to add `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__` to wraps, because they don't come for free...
my_wraps = partial(wraps, assigned=(list(WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS) + ['__defaults__', '__kwdefaults__']))

def g(a: float, b=10):
    return a * b

def f(a: int,  *, b=1):
    return a * b

# all is well (for now)...
assert f(3) == 3
assert g(3) == 30
```

Whether I do this:

```py
g = my_wraps(f)(g)
g(3)  # raises TypeError (missing required positional argument 'b'), expected
```

**or** this:

```py
f = my_wraps(g)(f)
f(3)  # raises TypeError (missing required positional argument 'b'), expected
```

my wrapped function breaks.

Comment: Vanilla `wraps` works fine, so the problem is in `my_wraps` rather than the standard library. What's the context here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what do you mean by "works fine"? Of course, it does what it does (essentially, copy the `WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS` attributes over). But what it does is notoriously (1) limited and (2) misleading (e.g. copies `__signature__` and `__annotations__` but not `__defaults__`). Don't take it from me, take it from others (e.g. https://hynek.me/articles/decorators/ or https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/blob/master/blog/01-how-you-implemented-your-python-decorator-is-wrong.md if you need known names to respect an opinion).

Comment: ...I mean e.g. `wraps(f)(g)(3)` doesn't throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: It seems it's again a misalignment of what we both call "works fine", @jonrsharpe. Indeed `wraps(g)(f)(3)` doesn't throw a `TypeError`, but the output is not consistent with the signature (`inspect.signature(wraps(g)(f))` is `(a: float, b=10)`, so 3 should be multiplied by 10). This is because `__defaults__` wasn't updated. See for example, that third-party `from boltons.funcutils import wraps` works as expected. And so do (the very popular) `wrapt` and `decorator` packages. Boltons works  for `wraps(f)(g)`, but not `wraps(g)(f)` in my example.

Comment: Then use one of those. Again, what's the *context* - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jonsharepe, I'm trying to understand why stdlib `wraps` breaks when involving keyword-only args, so I can use it instead of needing to pull a third-party package to just solve that problem.